# get the coordinate of a pixel by clicking on it in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, coordinates, axes

this is my first time to create a matlab GUI.

I want to get the coordinate of a pixel in an image by clicking on it using matlab, i created a Matlab GUI contains axes, and the axes contains the image by the following code:

```
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     axes(hObject);
     I = imread('cameraman.tif');
     imshow(I);
```

and for the `ButtonDownFcn` to get the coordinate of the clicked pixel:

```
function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     handles.xy1 = round(get(handles.axes1,'Currentpoint'));
     x1 = handles.xy1(1,1);
     y1 = handles.xy1(1,2);
```

the problem is that when i click on the image the `ButtonDownFcn` doesn't called, but when i remove the code from `CreateFcn` function, the `ButtonDownFcn` is called.

How to display the image and in the same time keep `ButtonDownFcn` working?

thanks,

Comment: You need it programatically to process them or just want to see them ?

Answer (score 1):

These functions need to be set. Something like this would work:

```
set(hFigure,'ButtonDownFcn', @axes1_ButtonDownFcn);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because of a weird behavior of `Matlab GUI` when you execute function `imshow` on an `Axes`, it reset Axes's properties.

You're seeing side effects of changes to axes properties that are made quietly by the image and surf commands. [ by Mathworks : [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/287296) ]

Try this code to show your image:

```
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
   axes(hObject);
   tag = get(hObject,'Tag');
   I = imread('cameraman.tif');
   imshow(I);
   set(hObject,'Tag',tag);
   set(hFigure,'ButtonDownFcn', @axes1_ButtonDownFcn);
end
```

and if you want only to see coordinates, use `Data Cursor` tool, Add it to your `GUI` from `Toolbar Editor` and you use it to navigate over `Axes` plot or image and show information from click position, and you can even change its action code.